# Is the use of semicolon applicable anywhere in this sentence?

Tags: semicolons

Here's the sentence -

> On further statistical analysis, these benefits were found to be both
>   short term (0-30 days) and long term (31-360 days) and in both STEMI
>   and UA/NSTEMI patients, irrespective of whether PCI was done or not.

I was tempted to write this sentence in the following way:

> On further statistical analysis, these benefits were found to be both
>   short term (0-30 days) and long term (31-360 days), and in both STEMI
>   and UA/NSTEMI patients; irrespective of whether PCI was done or not.

Any thoughts on what the right way is?

Answer (score 1):

It is rather a mouthful as it stands (version 1), though not ungrammatical.

However, using a semicolon would not be standard, as you would not be separating into two complete sentences. People could probably (and would probably) argue over whether it is incorrect to leave a sentence fragment on one side of a semicolon, though most people accept sentence fragments as not incorrect per se.

Brackets tend to be an acceptable stratagem:

> On further statistical analysis, these benefits were found to be both
>   short term (0-30 days) and long term (31-360 days), and in both STEMI
>   and UA/NSTEMI patients (irrespective of whether PCI was done or not).

However, the parenthesis could be seen as applying solely to the two classes of patients, so a second comma would be preferable here:

> On further statistical analysis, these benefits were found to be both
>   short term (0-30 days) and long term (31-360 days), and in both STEMI
>   and UA/NSTEMI patients, irrespective of whether PCI was done or not.

For absolute disambiguation, re-ordering is preferable:

> On further statistical analysis, irrespective of whether PCI was done
>   or not these benefits were found to be both short term (0-30 days) and
>   long term (31-360 days), and in both STEMI and UA/NSTEMI patients.

Comment: Your version makes absolute sense. Thanks! It would also be nice if you could comment on the use of comma after "(31-360 days)". Is there a general rule that governs that usage in lists such as this or is it just to make things more clear? Could that comma be left out? Appreciations!

Comment: There are many 'rules' governing comma usage. I think that some of them are so sensible that they deserve to _be_ rules. However, commas are nowadays sometimes omitted where they would once have been considered mandatory – and included where no one would consider them necessary, to signal a pause to the reader for stylistic reasons. Have a look through some of the relevant posts here. With your example, the comma divides cohesive sections of the sentence in a helpful way. _Just_ to make things more clear!? _Just_!? // I've decided that two commas show the structure better in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the original construction is perfectly grammatical, albeit bordering on a run-on sentence.

Your suggested edit is, in my opinoin, not grammatically correct. The bit after the semicolon must be able to stand on its own as a sentence.

So if you must have the ";", I would go with:

"On further statistical analysis, these benefits were found to be both short term (0-30 days) and long term (31-360 days), and in both STEMI and UA/NSTEMI patients; **this was** irrespective of whether PCI was done or not.",

which is grammatically sound but adds two rather unnecessary words. Still, it might be a little easier to parse.

Parentheses might be preferred by some, but that's largely subjective. I think the original construction is fine, especially for a scientific (medical) journal. Being grammatically perfect is less of a priority in the technical literature; it's rather more important to convey findings and meaning in an unambiguous fashion.

(See how I used the semicolon there?)

Are you the editor, the reviewer or (one of) the author(s) here?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Deepak! I'm one of the authors and this is my very first attempt at scientific writing. It's been a steep learning curve in terms of both academic and literary skills. 

Best, Aman.